# Raw sql query to be converted in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Following SQL code is my raw query for calculating lat long within radius of 5miles

```
select `appusers`.`id` as `appuser_id`, `appusers`.`profile_pic`, `appusers`.`first_name`, `appusers`.`last_name`, `appusers`.`dob`, `rides`.`no_of_seates`, `rides`.`pickup_address`, `rides`.`destination_address`, `rides`.`smoking`, `rides`.`pets`, `rides`.`luggage`, `rides`.`intermediate_locations`, `rides`.`picked_datetime`, `rides`.`drop_datetime`, `rides`.`status`, `rides`.`ride_charges`, `vehicle_details`.`vehicle_registration_number`, `vehicle_details`.`make`, `vehicle_details`.`model`, `ratings`.`ratings`,

TRUNCATE( ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 18.594726 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( `pickup_latitude` ) ) * COS( RADIANS( `pickup_longitude` ) - RADIANS( 73.7915588 ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 18.594726 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( `pickup_latitude` ) ) ) ) , 2 ) AS distance

FROM rides
inner join `appusers` on `appusers`.`id` = `rides`.`appuser_id` 
left join `ratings` on `rateable_id` = `rides`.`appuser_id`
inner join `vehicle_details` on `vehicle_details`.`id` = `rides`.`vehicle_details_id`

WHERE 'ride_status_id' =1
HAVING distance < 5 ORDER BY distance
```

How can i write it in Laravel using eloquent?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: yes i used db::raw but didnt work also i added truncate part to my eloquent query but i got radians undefined

Comment: This thread might help: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/haversine-query-using-eloquent?page=1

Comment: thanks that worked for me